# An indecomposable $A$-module is also indecomposable as a module of quotient algebra.

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a basic finite-dimensional associative algebra over field k, and let $P$ be an indecomposable projecitve -injective $A$-module. Define $B= A/soc(P)$, then there is a surjecive algebra homomorphism $f:A \rightarrow B$.

Let $X$ be any indecomposable $A$-module not isomorphic to $P$. Then how to get that $X$ is an indecomposable $B$-module?(I can get $X$ indecomposble if $X$ is a $B$-module, but I don't know how to get that $soc(P)_.X=0$.)

Comment: $soc(P)$ is a subset of $P$, not $A$. Are you assuming $P$ is given an explicit embedding into $A$? Or perhaps, consider all split injections $P \hookrightarrow A$?

Comment: @Dustan Levenstein Since $P$ is an indecomposable projective $A$-module, we have that $P$ is a direct summand of $A$ as $A$-modules. So there is a natural embedding $P \hookrightarrow A$

Comment: The embedding is not unique, though.